# AngularJS OpenLayers directive - does not work within angular-ui-dialog

Tags: angularjs, openlayers

I would like to use [AngularJS OpenLayers directive](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/) on my page - it works OK but when I put this directive into `angular-ui-dialog` it won't work.

I cannot see any error in console, any ideas what can be causing this?

Sample usage:

```
<openlayers width="100px" height="100px"></openlayers>
```

Plnkr with a demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YSfcKaTmNsSpkvSI6wt7?p=preview

Comment: If I embed openlayers code into the page, I see module registration errors, it works, i think. See the Plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mTE89KIMoeWmGybVY9bc?p=preview

The errors are raisen by a strict Mime type check, so i just tried embedding to see if i could further debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's some kind of a refreshing/rendering issue. You can go around it by adding map to DOM after modal is rendered.

[image: imgur]

**HTML template**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" 
        ng-click="demo.modal()">
        Open modal
</button>
<script type="text/ng-template" 
        id="modal.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Modal window</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <openlayers width="100px" 
                height="100px" 
                ng-if="modal.rendered"> <!-- ng-if adds/removes DOM elements -->
    </openlayers>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" 
            ng-click="$dismiss()">
            Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'openlayers-directive'])
.controller('demoController', function($q, $modal) {
  var demo = this;
  demo.modal = function() {
    $modal.open({
      controller: 'modalController',
      controllerAs: 'modal',
      templateUrl: 'modal.html'
    });
  };
})
.controller('modalController', function($modalInstance, $timeout) {
  var modal = this;
  modal.rendered = false;

  $modalInstance.rendered.then(function() { // magic here
    $timeout(function() {
      modal.rendered = true;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems that it works only if called within rendered promise, thanks!